# ChromeWorker File Not including in the extension package

Tags: multithreading, firefox-addon, worker

Hi I am building a Mozilla Extension through CFX tool. I have used ChromeWorker in it. It is working fine while i am running : cfx run command. But while building up a package using cfx xpi the Chrome Worker file is not included in the xpi package. 
I am using this to create the worker thread.
var tworker = new ChromeWorker("chrome://addons/content/t_worker.js");

my t_worker.js file is present in addons/lib

I have also put one chrome.manifest file in the package that contains :
content addons ./resources/addons/lib/

Please tell the possible reason for this problem and also how to fix it .

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your file into the data folder then do:

```
const self = require('sdk/self');
var tworker = new ChromeWorker(self.data.url('t_worker.js')
```

im totally not sure of this syntax, i just typed off top of my head

Answer (score 0):

I putted that worker file in the lib thats why its not working. I just changed the location of my file to data folder and made changes in my chrome.manifest file : content addons ./resources/addons/**data(previously it was lib)**/ . Its working fine  Thanks to @Noitidart for the suggestion of putting it in data folder